# How to disable select and activate and return to just select tool

Tags: interface

How to disable the select and move tool  and return to just select tool in the blender interface

I'm using Blender 2.8 on Ubuntu 18.04 with default settings.

[image: select and move]
[image: just select]

Comment: To get rid from no longer needed tool, just click on cross-hair in the toolbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toolbar buttons with a little arrow at the bottom right can be expanded to reveal more sub-tools or options.

Just click continuously on the *Selection Tool* toolbar button to expand the dropdown, and pick any of the available tools from there.

[image]